# How do I solve this memory error in Java from regex pattern?

Tags: java, memory

I am calling it as follows:

```
val (from, to) = my_input()
```

The error message is:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-1-thread-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Comment: `from to to` - pro tip. probably not a good idea to have a variable named the same as a keyword.

Comment: @selbie you're right, I renamed it to ```new_spot```. Do you know what the key word "to" does? In python you could just return it with commas ```return (from, new_spot)```

Comment: Your code works correctly, but I am able to reproduce OOM Exception using kotlinlang.org environment: https://pl.kotl.in/3wYY3SAVE . The problem arises from the readLine() which returns null, apparently this site does not allow user input. Your while loop in such case turns into never ending loop, and the regex operations causes allocations which exceeds this environment quotas.

Comment: One other point worth mentioning about this code is the repeated compiling of the regex, i.e. calling `toRegex()` every time. Compiling a regex takes time and memory, so it would be more efficient to do that only once, by defining a class value or top-level value for it (e.g. `val myRegex = "\\s*(\\d+),(\\d+)\\s+to\\s+(\\d+),(\\d+)\\s*".toRegex()`), and then referring to that. That's highly unlikely to be the main cause of running out of memory, but it would probably help a little. (Also, there's no need to declare `input` outside the loop.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning Kotlin too at the moment. I'm not sure if your out of memory error is an issue with the language or your particular install. But I do know that regular expressions can be problematic in any programming language.   Or as a friend put it, regular expression code is "WORNA" (write once, read never again).

Your problem of parsing `a,b to x,y` seems like it can be solved with a similar number of lines of code using `split` and `toIntOrNull`.

```
fun promptUser(): Pair<Pair<Int, Int>, Pair<Int, Int>> {

    var fromRow : Int? = null
    var fromCol : Int? = null
    var toRow : Int? = null
    var toCol : Int? = null

    print("Enter move (ex. '3,2 to 4,3'): ")

    while (fromRow == null || fromCol == null || toRow == null || toCol == null) {

        val input = readLine()?.trim() ?: ""

        val firstSplit = input.split("to") // change to .split(" to ") if you want to enforce spacing
        if (firstSplit.size == 2) {
            val leftSide = firstSplit[0].split(",")
            val rightSide = firstSplit[1].split(",")

            if ((leftSide.size == 2) && (rightSide.size == 2)) {
                fromRow = leftSide[0].trim().toIntOrNull()
                fromCol = leftSide[1].trim().toIntOrNull()
                toRow = rightSide[0].trim().toIntOrNull()
                toCol = rightSide[1].trim().toIntOrNull()
            }
        }
        if (fromRow == null || fromCol == null || toRow == null || toCol == null) {
            println("Invalid input. Please enter a move in the format 'row,column to row,column'.")
        }
    }

    val fromPoint = Pair(fromRow - 1, fromCol - 1)
    val toPoint = Pair(toRow - 1, toCol - 1)

    return fromPoint to toPoint
}
```

I don't know if this solves your question, but I learned a few things from reading your question.

Comment: This fixed the memory problem. I will stay away from regex in the future. Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with regexes — they can be tough to learn, but form the best solution to some problems. In this case, regexes can certainly work, and are likely to be a little more concise and easier to read. But manual splitting can work too, as this answer demonstrates.